# How to OnMouseIn and OnMouseOut element the effect other element correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want when I hover over an element and then it changes the state of the other elements. What I want is when I mouseover the table, then alter the CSS of the next button.

I am having trouble in table hover button does not change.

Preview: [image]

I want to hover at the table when the button is also like when the button hover.

Preview: [image]

You can visit this problem at [this URL](https://stage.travelcar.co.id/travel-MLG-SUBJ).

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("tr.accordion td").on({
        mouseover: function() {
            $("a.mau-pilih-travel").addClass("mau-pilih-hover")
        },
        mouseout: function() {
            $("a.mau-pilih-travel").removeClass("mau-pilih-hover")
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS class to change button state:

```
.mau-pilih-hover{
    background: #31BC86;
    color:#fff !important;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #888888;
}
```

Can you find my problem and the solution?

Comment: Maybe you can simply use `tr:hover .other-selector { .. }`?

Comment: Can you share your table?

Comment: you can find my problem at https://stage.travelcar.co.id/travel-MLG-SUBJ

Comment: @user2915402 thanks that's can be simplified by CSS.. i have try these codes
tr:hover .mau-pilih-travel, tr:hover .mau-pilih-travel:before {
background: #31BC86;
color: #fff !important;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #888888;
}
n works (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your code for this

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("tr.accordion td").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(".mau-pilih-travel").addClass("mau-pilih-hover")
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $(".mau-pilih-travel").removeClass("mau-pilih-hover")
    }
});
});
</script>
```